# Rails: dynamic columns/attributes on models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design

I have a SaaS application, where accounts want to save different types of information on a User model. So for example, one account may want to save age, and birthdate, but in another account, they won't be using those columns and will want to save info on hair color, and height.

These are just examples, but how would I structure my model and db so that it works well with "customized, dynamic" columns without creating too many empty attributes.

Comment: jc, where'd you end up going with this?

Comment: @mmcrae I ended up using postgresql's .json data structure, and dumped any custom column into this .json data field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me this sound like a perfect example were you want to use a schema free NoSQL database.

Or (if you want to stick with SQL) you can have a base `User` model with a `has_many :attributes` association. In which a attribute is just a combination of a `key` ('age', 'birthday', 'hair color') and a value. Complexity comes with different datatypes and queries covering multiple attributes at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

Here are the two options.
1. NoSQL database.
2. [Rails 4 Store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) feature.

Comment: Rails Store looks really interesting and suitable for many cases where you want to stick with your usual database and models, and "when you don't care about being able to query that store outside the context of a single record" - to quote from the documentation. Perfect for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Postgresql you can take a look at hstore then you can save the information serialized and actually you can make some queries against those hashes btw Rails 4 has included this feature but if you are using an older Rails version you can include this gem. https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore in your Gemfile and you should be able to start playing like:

```
user = User.new
user.preferences = {
  email: "p@elh.mx",
  github: "heridev"
}

user.save!
user.reload

# Searching
User.where("preferences @> hstore(:key, :value)", key: "email", value: "p@elh.mx").first
```

Answer (score 2):

Made a gem for that, if you wanna keep using relational DB

https://github.com/Liooo/dynabute

Answer (score 0):

Your schema could be like:

```
create_table "accounts", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "data_key"
  t.string   "data_value"
end
```

Account model

```
belongs_to :user    
DATA_KEYS = ['age', 'birthdate', 'hair_color', 'height' ] # etc..
```

User model

```
has_many :accounts
Account::DATA_KEYS.each do |method|
  # getter method
  define_method(method) do
    accounts.find_by_data_key(method).try(:data_value)
  end

  # setter method
  define_method("#{method}=") do |value|
    data = accounts.find_or_initialize_by_data_key(method)
    data.data_value = value.strip
    data.save
  end
end
```

You can get and set account data values

E.g. `user.age` => will return age of user

`user.hair_color = 'brown'`  => will set hair color

Comment: Would this code change at all if User belonged to many Accounts? And Accounts would select whether they want to support a certain data_key, and the users in that account would have data_values on those data_keys

Comment: I am getting this error: "NoMethodError: undefined method `find_by_data_key' for #<User:0x00000109a7da00>"

Comment: @kibaekr, User model has `has_many :accounts` And `find_by_data_key` method is not for `User` object but it is for `Account` model.

Comment: Yes, so i modified your example a bit, to get it working without account first. this is what i did  https://gist.github.com/kibaekr/3225f20dbcb0858a0558

Comment: @kibaekr, `data_key` column is in `accounts` table and not in `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going for a NoSQL database. They are designed specifically for such cases and so you won't have to do crazy stuff to make things work. [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) combined with [MongoID](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/index.html) is a very solid solution.

The only downside might be the hosting as it tends to be slightly, at least, more expensive.